# Time a rocky satellite in lunar "frozen" orbit spends in Earth's umbra during total lunar eclipse

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, gravity, mass, reconnaissance-satellite

I am wondering how long a large satellite in a [lunar frozen orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frozen_orbit) would remain in the Earth's umbra during a total lunar eclipse.

The satellite is spheroid with a diameter of 200 km. Let us say that it is composed of exactly the same material as the Moon itself.

I am aware that the mass of such an object is considerably larger than that of satellites like the lunar reconnaissance orbiter, which maintain a frozen orbit. It is possible that such a large satellite could not even maintain a frozen orbit.

I understand that the shadow of the Earth *does not* pass in a straight line across the Moon's surface during an eclipse. I understand that it may be extremely difficult to calculate exactly where the hypothetical satellite would be at the time of totality, so let us assume that *at the start of totality* our satellite enters the Earth's umbra. I am going on the basic assumption that totality for this hypothetical total lunar eclipse will last for approximately 2 hours. The satellite will not alter its speed under its own agency at any time.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your edits, uhoh! Much appreciated!

Comment: Since lunar eclipses are extremely short compared to the timescale associated with orbital instabilities, as long as the satellite's orbit was okay for say a week prior, a few hours of lunar eclipse would not make any difference. The Earth is always pulling on the Moon and its artificial satellites, and every lunar month during a full moon the Sun and Earth line up *almost* exactly anyway (even without the eclipse) so I don't see anything special about this situation from an orbital mechanics point of view.

Comment: no problem, *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Just fyi, from [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) see [How do comment `@replies` work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080)